# string-rectangle command pollutes kill-ring after upgrade to Emacs 25

Tags: linux, kill-ring, rectangle

In Emacs 24 I used to have a workflow for inserting a string into multiple lines at once:

1. Go to the desired position in the first line.
2. Press <kbd>C-Space</kbd> to place the mark.
3. Go to the last line (while remaning in the same column).
4. Press <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> for the `string-rectangle` command.
5. Input the desired string into the minibuffer by either

   1. typing it
   2. or pressing <kbd>C-y</kbd> (`yank`) to use the most recent kill.
6. Finally hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

After upgrading from Emacs 24 to 25, I found that step 5.2 inserts what I just selected in steps 1 to 3: pressing <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> behaves as if I had pressed <kbd>M-w</kbd> (`kill-ring-save`) as well. As a result, I have to press and extra <kbd>M-y</kbd> (`yank-pop`) in step 5.2.

Is there any way to prevent the selection from getting pushed onto the kill ring when invoking `string-rectangle`?

Please note that I use Xorg, so the X clipboard also affects Emacs's kill ring. Additionally, I have a clipboard manager running (Diodon) that synchronizes the X clipboard and the X primary selection (which is basically the last text selected using the mouse). So the selection may end up on top of the kill ring through either the X clipboard or the X primary selection. Nonetheless, this didn't use to happen in Emacs 24 and I would not like it to happen in Emacs 25 either.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem in `emacs -Q` using Emacs-25.1.  My guess is this problem is triggered by something in your local configuration.